# Excluding the NaN values while doing a Sum operation across the rows inside FOR Loop

Tags: python

I am  having two data frame as given below

```
df1=
   2492  3853  2486  3712  2288
0    4   NaN   3.5   NaN   NaN
1    3   NaN   2.0   4.5   3.5
2    3   3.5   4.5   NaN   3.5
3    3.   NaN   3.5   4.5   NaN


df2=

2492  0.476683
3853  0.464110
2486  0.438992
3712  0.400275
2288  0.379856
```

Right now I would like to get the sum of df2 values by excluding the NaN Values
Expected output

```
0    0.915675[0.476683+0.438992]
1    1.695806[0.476683+0.438992+0.400275+0.379856]
2    1.759641[0.476683+0.464110+0.438992+0.379856]    
3    1.31595 [0.476683+0.438992+0.400275]
```

Please let me know your thoughts how to achieve this issue(without replacing NaN values as "0" )

Comment: does one of the answer below solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
df2.sum(1).sum()
```

Should be enough and skip NaNs.

The first `sum` is a DataFrame method that returns a Series which contains the sum for every line, then the second is summing the values on this Series.

NaNs are ignored by default.

**edit**: using simply `df2.sum()` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> ((df1.fillna(0)>0)*1).mul(df2.iloc[:,1].values).sum(axis=1)
0    0.915675
1    1.695806
2    1.759641
3    1.315950
dtype: float64
```

Note that `NaN` are not replaced "by reference", you still have `NaN` in your original `df1` after this operation.